# Xamarin Forms Collapsable StackLayout

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to implement a kind of collapsable StackLayout.
Every tine the user clicks the button, it expands or collapse the stacklayout to show/hide more details.

[image]

I was able to achieve more/less this with the code below, but it doesn't look right and the effect isn't great, because it grows immediately and I'm applying the effect to other element.

Do you have any suggestions to do this, I'm using xamarin Forms?

**XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Sample.MyStackLayout" >

  <StackLayout x:Name="TopLayout">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Label Text="some text" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  />
      <Label Text="123" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" FontSize="Large" />
    </StackLayout>

    <BoxView Color="Black" HeightRequest="1" />

    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Label Text="some text" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  />
      <Label Text="123" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" FontSize="Large" />
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Label Text="some text" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  />
      <Label Text="123" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" FontSize="Large" />
    </StackLayout>

    <Button x:Name="btn" Text="Button" Clicked="btnClicked" />
  </StackLayout>


  <StackLayout x:Name="MoreDetails" IsVisible="False">
    <Label Text="some text 1"></Label>
    <Label Text="some text 2"></Label>
    <Label Text="some text 3"></Label>
    <Label Text="some text 4"></Label>
    <Label Text="some text 5"></Label>
    <Label Text="some text 6"></Label>
    <Label Text="some text 7"></Label>
    <Label Text="some text 8"></Label>
  </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

**Code**

```
public AccountInfo()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

bool isExpanded = false;
protected async void btnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isExpanded)
    {
        await MoreDetails.FadeTo(0);
        MoreDetails.IsVisible = !isExpanded;
    }
    else
    {
        MoreDetails.IsVisible = !isExpanded;
        await MoreDetails.FadeTo(1);
    }

    isExpanded = !isExpanded;
}
```

Comment: Functionality is now integrated in Xamarin form you can try it out it's much more stable https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/expander

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a Custom control that does this for you.  If you create an 'ExpandableView' Content View with Xaml like:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="MyProject.CustomControls.ExpandableView">
    <StackLayout  x:Name="Layout" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout x:Name="SummaryRegion"/>               
        <StackLayout x:Name="DetailsRegion" IsVisible="False"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

And wire up the .cs class like so:

```
    public partial class ExpandableView: ContentView
    {

        private TapGestureRecognizer _tapRecogniser;
        private StackLayout _summary;
        private StackLayout _details;

        public ExpandableView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeGuestureRecognizer();
            SubscribeToGuestureHandler();    
        }

        private void InitializeGuestureRecognizer()
        {
            _tapRecogniser= new TapGestureRecognizer();
            SummaryRegion.GestureRecognizers.Add(_tapRecogniser);
        }

        private void SubscribeToGuestureHandler()
        {
            _tapRecogniser.Tapped += TapRecogniser_Tapped;
        }

        public virtual StackLayout Summary
        {
            get { return _summary; }
            set
            {
                _summary = value;    
                SummaryRegion.Children.Add(_summary);
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public virtual StackLayout Details
        {
           get { return _details; }
           set 
           {
              _details = value;
              DetailsRegion.Children.Add(_details);
              OnPropertyChanged();
           }
       }

       private void TapRecogniser_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DetailsRegion.IsVisible)
        {
            DetailsRegion.IsVisible = false;
        }
        else
        {
             DetailsRegion.IsVisible = true;
        }
    }
```

And define it in your xaml like so:

```
                     <CustomControls:ExpandableView>
                            <CustomControls:ExpandableView.Summary>
                                   <StackLayout>
                                    YOUR STUFF HERE 
                                </StackLayout>
                            </CustomControls:ExpandableView.Summary>
                            <CustomControls:ExpandableView.Details>
                                <StackLayout>
                                    YOUR STUFF HERE 
                                </StackLayout>
                            </CustomControls:ExpandableView.Details>
                        </CustomControls:ExpandableView>
```

Where CustomControls is the reference to namespace where the ExpandableView exists.

You can expand this further by adding things such as animations on expand, highlight the 'Summary Region' when expanded etc...

Comment: Would you mind writing me a little bit more details how should I implement your code? The first XAML should be in one file correct? And the C# code should be in the CS file of that XAML view? So where should be the second XAML code presented by you?

Comment: Yeah so you'll have one XAML file that will be called something like ExpandableView.xaml which contains the first snippet, now this XAML file is NOT a ContentPage, it is a 'ContentView'.  Next you'll have the ExpandableView.xaml.cs contain the second snippet.  Then in your actual Page you'll have the code from the third snippet.   You'll need make sure your page can see the custom control file.

Answer (score 2):

In your APP class, add flag to enable experimental feature:

```
Device.SetFlags(new string[] { "Expander_Experimental" });
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
<Expander>
<Expander.Header>
    <StackLayout>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="One label" />
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="One label" />
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Text="One label" />

            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="123" />
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="123" />
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="123" />

            <Image x:Name="Your_Image_DropDown" Grid.Row="3" 
             Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Source="YOUR IMAGE LINK/SOURCE HERE" 
             HorizontalOptions="Center"/>


        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</Expander.Header>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="One label" />
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="One label" />
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Text="One label" />

    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="123" />
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="123" />
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="123" />

  </Grid>
  </Expander>
```

For more information
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/expander

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your everything but MoreDetails to another stack layout and name it "TopLayout"

```
  void ShowMore(){
    TopLayout.TranslateTo(0, -TopLayout.Bounds.Height, 300,  Easing.Linear);
    MoreDetails.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(0, 0, MoreDetails.Bounds.Width, MoreDetails.Bounds.Height + TopLayout.Bounds.Height), 300, Easing.Linear);
    }

    void ShowLess(){
    TopLayout.TranslateTo(0, 0, 300,  Easing.Linear);
    MoreDetails.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(0, MoreDetails.Bounds.Height, MoreDetails.Bounds.Width, MoreDetails.Bounds.Height - MoreDetails.Bounds.Height), 300, Easing.Linear);
    }
```

100  -  here is your displacement value

As a bonus:

```
MoreLessImage.RotateXTo(180, Duration, TargetEasing);
```

you can morph your button like this to animate ShowMore/ShowLess image

Comment: Sorry I might doing something wrong, but I pasted your code and didn't work as expected. My ideia is remove (hide) the lower stacklayout. Btw Easing.None doesn't exist in my version of Xamarin forms, so I'm using Linear. I wrapped all main contents in a StackLayout as well, so I have [StackLayout > StackLayout TopLayout AND StackLayout ModerDetails]

Comment: Thanks for the help but doesn't compile, TranslateTo takes this params: double x, double y, uint length = 250, Easing easing = null. Btw you are missing "()" after ShowMore and ShowLess

Comment: Yes, sorry, for that, i was implementing exactly similiar layout, and writing from memory. Edited

Comment: No luck. When showless the MoreDetails panel disappear but the parent doesn't resize. On showMore the MoreDetails appears but scrolls on top of TopLayout. :(

Comment: Are you sure you are calling correct function? Try to start with showMore

Comment: no doesn't work, I tried changed the order and doesn't work, the panels overlap each other. I edited my question, I changed the code to use isVisibleand fadeout, it works ok but I just don't have the growing/shrink effect.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve collapsible view using **Xamarin Community Toolkit's [Expander](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/expander)**. Xamarin Community Toolkit also provides a lot of views, controls, behaviors, extensions, effects, etc.