# XamarinForms sticky header

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

Im searching for a solution represented here as a gif from my designer: [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cKeJmc8Arnp3haXF77mpECIX9R_QH_48/view)

Basically, I need a list, with a header, or with a another view (grid, or stacklayout). On a scroll, I need to catch event (scrolling down, scrolling up) and to move list with that header.
Can you suggest me some referrals?
Here is the example code from syncfusion:
https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/AnimateHeaderOnScroll1119606059

Comment: HI go through these links

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/129124/scroll-effect-with-collapsing-sections-of-the-screen

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/BikeSharing360_MobileApps

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/BikeSharing360_MobileApps

Comment: this code doesnt work in .net standard 2.0

Comment: you can get some idea from these

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620775/xamarin-forms-collapsable-stacklayout

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/169747/collapse-on-scroll-for-a-profile-page

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement by handling Scrolled event as below,

```
public MainPage() 
{ 
            InitializeComponent(); 
            container = _listView.GetVisualContainer(); 
            _scrollView = _listView.GetScrollView(); 
            _scrollView.Scrolled += ScrollView_Scrolled; 
} 

private void ScrollView_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e) 
{ 
    scrollOffet = (double)container.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties().First(p => p.Name == "ScrollOffset").GetValue(container); 

    if (e.ScrollY == 0) 
        (BindingContext as MainViewModel).CanPassTouch = true; 
} 

private void PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if(e.StatusType == GestureStatus.Running) 
    { 
        var y = e.TotalY; 

        //Up scroll 
        if (y < 0) 
        { 
            if (!_originalHeaderHeight.HasValue) 
            { 
                _originalHeaderHeight = _headerView.Height; 
            } 
            var newHeight = _originalHeaderHeight.Value + y; 
            _headerView.HeightRequest = newHeight > MIN_HEADER_HEIGHT ? newHeight : MIN_HEADER_HEIGHT; 
        } 
        //Down scroll 
        else 
        { 
            if (!_originalHeaderHeight.HasValue) 
            { 
                _originalHeaderHeight = _headerView.Height; 
            } 
            var newHeight = _originalHeaderHeight.Value + y; 
            _headerView.HeightRequest = newHeight < MAX_HEADER_HEIGHT ? newHeight : MAX_HEADER_HEIGHT; 
        } 

        //Enable InputTransparent for SfListView, to enable the ListView scrolling 
        //after reaching the Header min/max heights based on scrolling. 
        if (_headerView.HeightRequest == MIN_HEADER_HEIGHT && y < 0) 
            (BindingContext as MainViewModel).CanPassTouch = false; 
        if (_headerView.HeightRequest == MAX_HEADER_HEIGHT && scrollOffet > 0) 
            (BindingContext as MainViewModel).CanPassTouch = false; 
    } 
}
```

[Sample](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/27843343168966)

Comment: Nope, still is not good, it has jumping effect when I scroll to the half of header max height. Here is the example:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q0pT1p6yIsx5Yz9vxP36BVfKSIy6b_69/view?usp=sharing

Comment: We are unable to access the google drive link which is provided by you. Can you please share the sample in the zip format or give the accessible drive link to get the sample?